# TypeError: Cannot read property 'loading' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-props

I am getting that error.
And I honestly do not why.

I passing loading as a prop. Its in my Redux store.

The initial state of loading is false

When I  submit, loading should change to true and you should see the errors (If the email is not legit for example)

signup.js

```
class signup extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            confirmPassword: '',
            handle: '',
            errors: {}
        };
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.UI.errors) {
            this.setState({ errors: nextProps.UI.errors });
        }
    }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            loading: true
        })
        const newUserData = {
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password,
            confirmPassword: this.state.confirmPassword,
            handle: this.state.handle
        };

        this.props.signupUser(newUserData, this.props.history);
    }


    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
    }


    render() {


        const {
            classes,
            UI: { loading } // Thats my ERROR
        } = this.props;
        const { errors } = this.state;


        return (
            <Grid container className={classes.form}>
                <Grid item sm />
                <Grid item sm>
                    <Typography variant="h2" className={classes.pageTitle}>
                        Signup
          </Typography>
                    <form noValidate onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <TextField
                            id="email"
                            name="email"
                            type="email"
                            label="Email"
                            className={classes.textField}
                            helperText={errors.email}
                            error={errors.email ? true : false}
                            value={this.state.email}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            fullWidth
                        />
                      ....... // Not important
                     
                        {errors.general && (
                            <Typography variant="body2" className={classes.customError}>
                                {errors.general}
                            </Typography>
                        )}
                        <Button
                            type="submit"
                            variant="contained"
                            color="primary"
                            className={classes.button}
                            disabled={loading}

                        >
                            Sgnup
                            {loading && (
                                <CircularProgress size={30} className={classes.progress} />
                            )}
                        </Button>
                        <br />
                        <small>All ready have  an account ? login in <Link to="/login">here</Link></small>
                    </form>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item sm />
            </Grid>
        )
    }
}

signup.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    user: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    UI: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    signupUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    user: state.user,
    UI: state.UI
})


export default connect(mapStateToProps, { signupUser })(withStyles(styles)(signup));
```

Ui Reducer.js
The initial state of loading is false
I passing it as a prop to signup.js (and login.js)

```
import {
    SET_ERRORS,
    CLEAR_ERRORS,
    LOADING_UI,
    STOP_LOADING_UI
} from '../types';

const initialState = {
    loading: false,
    errors: null
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_ERRORS:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                errors: action.payload
            };
        case CLEAR_ERRORS:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                errors: null
            };
        case LOADING_UI:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

that is my store.js

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'


import userReducer from './reducers/userReducer'

import uiReducer from './reducers/uiReducer'

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk]

const reducers = combineReducers({
    user: userReducer,

    ui: uiReducer
})



const composeEnhancers =
    typeof window === 'object' && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
        ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({})
        : compose;

const enhancer = composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware));
const store = createStore(reducers, initialState, enhancer);

export default store
```

I would appreciate any help

Comment: where is the UI state  in your reducer?

Comment: can you share your combineReducers?

Comment: sure I can do that ( one minute please) / its my first time using react redux :D

Comment: @DenisSicun points out the issue. your partial state at combineReducers is `ui` instead of `UI`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem in the combineReducers or in the mapStateToProps.
In the reducer it's ui with small letters, and in the mapStateToProps it's capital.
Change to this and it should work

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    user: state.user,
    UI: state.ui
})
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I see two errors. One, I think you are trying to update a Redux state by using React state function and that's not how it works. If its a state living within a React Component, then React.setState should be the way to go. If you are using Redux, then I am assuming that the proper way of updating its via Redux actions/dispatch from the component itself. I hope this gives you a starting to debug it. And two, Redux store is not set properly or that object destructuring is not working as you expected.

Comment: Could you show, in which line I am updating a redux state by using a react state ? (handleSubmit)

Answer (score 1):

Well, your problem at the moment is in the `store.js`. You define `initialState = {}` and pass it as an argument to `createStore`. This empty object is then actually used instead of the `initialState` defined in `Reducer.js`. This object is passed on as props to the `signup` class. Thus you cannot extract the `UI.loading` value, because there is not one.

import the initial state from `Reducer.js` and use it instead of the empty `initialState` when calling `createStore`.